# C++ WCHAR and WString on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

wchar_t and wchar_t*, and wstring not supported well on Android. I was wondering what the story is on ios.  Would a library containing wide string functions and variables run ok on ios? would it need to be recompiled?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use these types? They might not be suitable for what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does support the whcar_t and std::wstring types. One thing to note though is that wchar_t on iOS is 32 bits wide rather than 16 bits wide. This may cause cross-platform issues.